# <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError'> (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I want to insert dataframe to oracle but I get ORA-01843 error.
Iam using sqlalchemy, cx_oracle, python and oracle 12c

Here is my NLS_DATE_FORMAT from oracle: DD/MM/YYYY

FILE_DATE: DATE Column / 
ID: Number(38,0) Column / 
VALUE: Float Column

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO "TEST" ("FILE_DATE", "ID", "VALUE") VALUES (:FILE_DATE, :ID, :VALUE)]
[parameters: [{'FILE_DATE': '03/10/2019', 'ID': '407', 'VALUE': 0.0}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': '03/10/2019', 'ID': '407', 'VALUE': 0.100000024}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': '03/10/2019', 'ID': '407', 'VALUE': 0.199999988}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': '03/10/2019', 'ID': '407', 'VALUE': 0.300000012}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': '03/10/2019', 'ID': '407', 'VALUE': 0.399999976}]]
```

I also try this:

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO "TEST" ("FILE_DATE", "ID", "VALUE") VALUES (:FILE_DATE, :ID, :VALUE)]
[parameters: [{'FILE_DATE': "to_date('03/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')", 'ID': '406', 'VALUE': 0.0}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': "to_date('03/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')", 'ID': '406', 'VALUE': 0.100000024}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': "to_date('03/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')", 'ID': '406', 'VALUE': 0.199999988}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': "to_date('03/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')", 'ID': '406', 'VALUE': 0.300000012}, 
              {'FILE_DATE': "to_date('03/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')", 'ID': '406', 'VALUE': 0.399999976}]]
```

where am I wrong?

Comment: If this is a pandas DataFrame you're talking about, have you tried just using [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: I have to insert big data like millions of row so to_sql is really slow.

Comment: In that case you should look into using something like SQL*Loader.

Comment: How did you set NLS_DATE_FORMAT?  If you used an environment variable then you will also need to set NLS_LANG.

Comment: I set NLS_DATE_FORMAT just before inserting with using cx_oracle's connection engine.
    conn.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MON/YYYY'")
    conn.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN'")

Comment: After that I also try this but again fail.

Comment: [SQL: INSERT INTO "TEST" ("FILE_DATE", "ID", "VALUE") VALUES (:FILE_DATE, :ID, :VALUE)]
[parameters: {'FILE_DATE': '03/Oct/2019', 'ID': '437', 'VALUE': 0.0}]